# Привязка к службе по applicationId

Tags: android, android-service, android-binder

У меня есть 2 приложения: приложение-клиент и приложение-сервер. Приложение-сервер содержит службу, к которой привязывается клиент. Вот как происходит привязка:

```
 Intent start = new Intent("com.example.myservice.ACTION_BIND");
 start.setPackage("com.example.myservice");
 startService(start);
 bindService(start, mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
```

Все работало хорошо, пока мне не потребовалось добавить в приложение-сервер productFlavors. В productFlavors я изменил applicationId и после этого приложение-клиент перестало привязываться к приложению-серверу. Приложение-клиент не знает с какой версией приложения-сервера работает.

Как можно программно получить applicationId приложения-сервера?

Answer (score 2):

У меня были проекты с productFlavors, я использовал BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID, например так:

```
static ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName( BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID, Widget.class.getName() );
```

Comment: Это если в одном приложении?! Мне нужно получить applicationId другого приложения.

Comment: А если передать через intent.putExtra

Comment: Куда передать? Приложение-сервер на то и сервер, что инициирует общение клиент.

Comment: Ну при привязке я имею ввиду. А сервер вытащит "extra" и узнает какой клиент это послал.

Comment: Вы не поняли наверное. Все наоборот. Это клиенту нужно узнать applicationId сервера, чтобы привязаться.

Comment: У вас 2 разных проекта? Проект сервер с productFlavors и проект клиент без них?

Comment: Да. Два разных проекта.

Comment: У вас вопрос должен быть намного короче: Как проверить возможность привязки к сервису (вы развели ненужные подробности). bindService вам возвратит это. Что у вас за алгоритм? Вы все равно будете пытаться привязаться сначала к серверу 1, потом 2.